# Output random entry from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to output a random selection of items stored in an array. There are three different arrays, and I want to output four items from each one. So 12 words to appear on the page.

Here is an example of the live site. Where you see the white squares, they're supposed to be words but I can't get it working: http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/

I have three arrays with 20 words each:

```
<?php
$poolOne=array("sparkly","sporty","happy","confident","awesome","funny","awkward","mad","silly","dynamic",
"handsome","merry","horrid","funky","loud","chirpy","posh","clever","pretty","athletic");
shuffle($poolOne);

$poolTwo=array("pink","purple","melon","lemon","lime","red","blue","peach","rouge","green",
"ginger","blonde","brown","yellow","gold","violet","rainbow","maroon","indigo","silver");
shuffle($poolTwo);

$poolThree=array("zebra","lion","tiger","fish","ktten","butterfly","octopus","squid","puppy","bug",
"spider","cat","hamster","newt","frog","monkey","dog","rabbit","pig","sheep");
shuffle($poolThree);
?>
```

I've attempted to use `shuffle()` to shuffle up the numbers, and then call them out into my `span` randomly:

```
<div class="words one">
    <span><?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {echo $poolOne[$i];} ?></span>
    <span><?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {echo $poolOne[$i];} ?></span>
    <span><?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {echo $poolOne[$i];} ?></span>
    <span><?php for($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {echo $poolOne[$i];} ?></span>
</div>
```

I'm guessing this is not correct, or that I've done something wrong.

Ultimately I need to iterate through each array and output a random 4 into the spans.

Comment: You made a copy/paste error. See that you print data only from `$poolOne`.

Comment: What is it outputting? I don't see anything wrong with your code, aside from what @Grzegorz pointed out.

Comment: @Grzegorz hmm... no that is correct. I want to pull four words from pool one. I didn't copy pool2 and pool3 cos I didn't want to fill up the question with code.

Comment: @Francesca - I'm sorry but I am bit confused. Your code shows that you print 16 words. 4 words from `poolOne` then ... 4 words from `poolOne`, and that repeats again, and again. I suspect that it is wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `shuffle()` you can use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
foreach (array_rand($poolOne, 4) as $key) {
    echo $poolOne[$key];
}

foreach (array_rand($poolTwo, 4) as $key) {
    echo $poolTwo[$key];
}

foreach (array_rand($poolThree, 4) as $key) {
    echo $poolThree[$key];
}
```

The function returns an array of random (unique) keys of the array that you pass. If you only need four random elements of the array, this would be preferred over `shuffle()` which modifies the whole array.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KvygPU)

> Does it matter that my arrays are below this in the code?

Yes, it does. The arrays MUST be declared above this code, otherwise they're undefined by the time your code runs.

Comment: I've just put this into the site but it doesn't seem to work. Am I supposed to change $key to something? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Jack. Slow down. You make the very same mistake @Francesca does - you  copy/paste and you print data from the `$poolOne` array. She wrote her code 'ok' but did the same mistake as you did now.

Comment: @Grzegorz I don't know what you're talking about, I pull from different arrays each time.

Comment: Does it matter that my arrays are below this in the code? I've just updated it as per your code and still see an empty div.

Comment: @Francesca The arrays must be declared above.

Comment: @Jack - You have just modified the code :DDD No one see the blood on your keyboard now :DDD

Comment: @Grzegorz thanks! that was the problem. I see your comment about outputting only from pool one... it outputs the same thing four times. I've adjusted it now. Just need to add the span in. If you add that as an answer I can tick it for you.

Comment: @Francesca - Thank you. The answer was so small that let is stay that way.

Comment: @Francesca using `array_rand()` is actually better here, because you only want four items of the array; whereas `shuffle()` will shuffle the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Francesca - I am using Jack's suggestion to use `array_rand`.
Please remove your `shuffle` calls, and instead of that use this:

```
<div class="words one">
    <span><?php foreach( array_rand( $poolOne, 4 ) as $key ) { echo $poolOne[ $key ] ; } ?></span>
    <span><?php foreach( array_rand( $poolTwo, 4 ) as $key ) { echo $poolTwo[ $key ] ; } ?></span>
    <span><?php foreach( array_rand( $poolThree, 4 ) as $key ) { echo $poolThree[ $key ] ; } ?></span>
</div>
```

I am perfectly okay if you mark Jack's answer. I am upping his as he pointed out to use array_rand().